# Remove single category in sidebar in category list page in magento2

Tags: magento2, category, layout, sidebar

Remove single category in sidebar in category list page in magento2
[image]

Comment: What you means by single category?

Comment: yes I want to remove a single category  in the sidebar but category page is  not removed